# Trying to print out node values in XSLT using variable elements names

Tags: java, xslt, csv, transformation, xalan

So here's a problem that's been bugging me for the last few days. It should be fairly easy, but XSLT is just such a pain to debug. We're using Xalan 1.0 on java 1.6

Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rfb2>
    <rfb2_item>
        <VALDATE>2011-10-23</VALDATE>
        <FUND_ID>300</FUND_ID>
        <SEC_ID>34567</SEC_ID>
    </rfb2_item>
    <rfb2_item>
        <VALDATE>2011-1-09</VALDATE>
        <FUND_ID>700</FUND_ID>
        <SEC_ID>13587</SEC_ID>
    </rfb2_item>
    <rfb2_item>
        <VALDATE>2011-3-09</VALDATE>
        <FUND_ID>200</FUND_ID>
        <SEC_ID>999334</SEC_ID>
    </rfb2_item>
<rfb2>
```

We need to transform the XML into a comma-separated list of values for each rfb2_item, so the style sheet always iterates the rfb2_item nodes. We are using a parameter in the style sheet to control which elements of rfb2_item (valdate,fund_id,sec_id) that will be output, and in what order, for example

```
<xsl:param name="$outputElements" select="'VALDATE,FUND_ID'"/>
..outputs...

2011-10-23,300
2011-1-09,700
2011-3-09,200



<xsl:param name="$outputElements" select="'SEC_ID'"/>    
..outputs...

34567
13587
999334
```

Special case where if $outputElements is '*', just output the elements in the order they appear in the input xml

```
<xsl:param name="$outputElements" select="'*'"/>

..outputs...

2011-10-23,300,34567
2011-1-09,700,13587
2011-3-09,200,999334
```

So, my question is how do we write a template to create the desired output based on the $outputElements parameter? A working example would be great...

Comment: You forgot to ask the question. Unless you want someone to write the complete xslt for you - which they will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, FailedDev is right. Someone would write it for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:param name="outputElements" select=" 'FUND_ID,SEC_ID,VALDATE' " />

    <xsl:template match="rfb2_item">

        <xsl:for-each select="*[contains($outputElements, local-name()) or $outputElements = '*']">
            <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($outputElements, local-name(.)))" />
            <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Bit of explanation. The `xsl:for-each` is gonna select each element in the current `rfb2_item` for which the local name is contained in the `outputElements` parameter, or for which the `outputElements` parameter is `*` (which would always yield true if that's the case). It's then gonna sort those based on the length of the substring that goes before that local name in `outputElements`. Since this value becomes higher when the name occurs later in that parameter, this results in ordering based on your parameter.

Example: element `VALDATE` would yield `FUND_ID,SEC_ID` for the `substring-before` function, which in turn would yield 14 as string length. This is higher than the 8 that you'd get for `SEC_ID`, meaning the `VALDATE` value is ordered after `SEC_ID`.

After the `xsl:sort`, we're simply using `xsl:value-of` to output the element value. You might want to trim extraneous whitespace there. Finally, we're testing if the position is not equal to that of the last node in the current context (which is that of `xsl:for-each` **after** sorting) and if so, output a comma. This avoids outputting a comma after the last value.

The line break I've inserted using `xsl:text` assumes the Windows/DOS convention. Remove the `&#13;` if the file should only use new line characters for line breaks, instead of carriage return + new line.

Note that this does not escape commas in your CSV output! I'll leave that up to you. It could be interesting to look into using [extension functions](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions.html) for delegating this task to Java if it proves too difficult in XSLT/XPath.

Comment: Hey G_H, this is great, and it works. You just relieved a great deal of stress, thank you. I added <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> at the top of the style sheet to remove all white space. I did have a few questions. Is the sorting necessary? And the comments you made about string length have me concerned, do I need to consider that if 2 or more elements are of the same length, as in rfb2_item/E1 and rfb2_item/E2?

Comment: @RaffiM The sorting is there to make sure the output fields are in the order determined by your parameter, as I believe was one of the requirements. The string length that is checked is that of a substring if the **parameter**, not the content of the element being output. It's a trick to make sure the elements are output in the order specified in the parameter. Basically, the name of each element that must be output (`FUND_ID`, `VALDATE`...) will yield a different number. Those numbers establish an ordering based on the given parameter.

Comment: @G_H...that makes sense...one last question, we're trying to integrate your code into a larger style sheet and it's generating strange results. We know it works standalone, but the issue is in the way we're calling it. If we invoke your template (using xsl:call-template) from another template that's already matched on "/*", what would change in your template code to produce the same output?

Comment: @RaffiM `xsl:call-template` is for named templates. Mine uses input matching. You'd either need to change my template to a named one and call it with a `rfb2_item` node as context, or use `xsl:apply-templates` with a selection that targets those nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in this kind of situation it's worth looking at the possibility of generating or modifying XSLT code using XSLT. You can take the parameterization a lot further that way - for example controlling which fields are output, how they are sorted, whether they are grouped, selection criteria for which rows are selected, etc etc.